# Retrieving message in return done(error, user, info) for passport JS

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

How do I get the message and display it in my router.post('/auth')?

```
passport.use(new FacebookTokenStrategy({
    clientID: 'HIDDEN',
    clientSecret: 'HIDDEN'
    }, function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        console.log(profile);
        var user = {id: profile.id, first_name: profile.name[1], last_name: profile.name[0], email: profile.emails[0], profile_picture: profile.photos[0]};
        var error = null;
        return done(error, user, {message: "HOW TO RETRIEVE THIS MESSAGE!"});
  }
));
```

I've tried to retrieve this message by saying console.log(req.message) or console.log(req.session.message), I just don't know how to get it. I've also tried console.log(req.session.passport.message)

```
router.post('/auth', passport.authenticate('facebook-token'), function(req, res){
    console.log("Verifying");
    console.log("HOW TO LOG THAT MESSAGE HERE?");
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        console.log(req.session.passport.user);
    }else{
        console.log("NOT");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the third argument is passed in any way if the authentication was successful (which in your case it always is; by default, Passport will return a 401 when authentication was unsuccessful, and your handler wouldn't get called at all).

However, you can add extra properties to `req` if you configure the strategy to pass it to the verification callback:

```
passport.use(new FacebookTokenStrategy({
    clientID: 'HIDDEN',
    clientSecret: 'HIDDEN',
    passReqToCallback : true,
    }, function(req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
      req.message = 'Your Message Here';
      ...
    }
}))
```

And then in your handler, you can access it as `req.message` as well.